# Discarding elements outside viewport

Tags: algorithm, graphics, camera, viewport, intersection

My setup allows me to add elements to some arbitrary world space. An element has a (x,y) coord as well as some width and height.

I then render a sub-section of that world using a viewport/camera. Obviously, I don't want to process elements outside the viewport.

[image]

**Question**

- What is an efficient way to determine which elements are outside/inside the viewport?

Right now I'm iterating through each element and checking if any portion of it is visible, but adding more elements to the world makes this step very slow.

- Is there some way to somehow index each element so that only some of the elements are even considered to be checked for intersection with the viewport?

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming that the viewport moves and the elements don't:**

Have a list of tiles that are inside the viewport. Every time the viewport moves, you update that list. To add/remove a tile from said list, do a simple intersection test against each tile with the viewport. Since the viewport probably won't move as often as those tiles will be drawn/processed, you can only draw/process tiles inside that list, instead of considering every tile in the entire world.

Comment: This does not make sense. What do you mean "the viewport moves"? The viewport cannot move; it is fixed to the position of the physical device/screen.